Out of tree module does not get loaded at system startup
I have an out-of-tree kernel module for my device, which is configured through devicetree. The problem is that when the system boots the module does not get loaded by the kernel.
The only option to load it is to manually call modprobe mymodule, then kernel finds it (it is installed under /lib/modules/5.15.71+g95448dd0dc9b/extra/) and loads it correctly.
Here is a devicetree entry:
&fspi { 
    mydevice: mydevice@0 {
        compatible = "mycompany,mydriver";
        spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
        spi-rx-bus-width = <4>; /* 1 SPI Rx lines */
        spi-tx-bus-width = <4>; /* 1 SPI Tx line */
        reg = <0>;
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};

As well as part of my driver:
static const struct of_device_id mydriver_of_table[] = {
    { .compatible = "mycompany,mydriver" },     
    { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, mydriver_of_table);

static struct spi_mem_driver mydriver_driver = {
    .spidrv = {
        .driver = {
            .name = "mydriver",
            .of_match_table = mydriver_of_table
        },
    },
    .probe = mydriver_probe,
    .remove = mydriver_remove
};

module_spi_mem_driver(mydriver_driver);

In my opinion everything looks fine, especially given the fact that when I manually call modprobe the driver is loaded correctly. What can be wrong here? Does the fact that the module is out of tree impact the module loading process?
Edit. Ok, I'm kinda lost. I always thought that the only thing I need to match my driver and device described in devicetree is of_device_id, however it didn't work. Once I added spi_device_id and set .id_table it magically loaded my driver at boot. Why is that?
// I added this
static const struct spi_device_id ids[] = {
    { "mydevice", 0 },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(spi, ids);

static const struct of_device_id mydevice_of_table[] = {
    { .compatible = "mycompany,mydevice" },
    { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, mydevice_of_table);

static struct spi_mem_driver mydevice_driver = {
    .spidrv = {
        .driver = {
            .name = "mydevice",
            .of_match_table = mydevice_of_table
        },
        .id_table = ids
    },
    .probe = mydevice_probe,
    .remove = mydevice_remove
};


Have the /lib/modules/${KERNELVERSION}/modules.alias and modules.alias.bin files been updated on the target filesystem? They are normally updated by depmod when the module is installed.

Yes of course, this is the modules.alias content:
alias of:NTCmycompany,mydeviceC* mydriver
alias of:NTCmycompany,mydevice mydriver

@IanAbbott I updated my question. I'm kinda confused. Do I need both, spi_device_id and of_device_id to bind my device described in devicetree with my driver and load it at boot? Once I added spi_device_id (which was not present before) the kernel loaded the device at boot. Why is that? Why do I nedd spi_device_id and of_device_id at the same time?

I'm not sure, but there is a comment in the code of the __spi_register_driver function in "drivers/spi/spi.c" that reads: "For Really Good Reasons we use spi: modaliases not of: modaliases for DT so module autoloading won't work if we don't have a spi_device_id as well as a compatible string." See commit 5fa6863ba692 for the Really Good Reasons.

Some more info in commit 96c8395e2166.

In short, it was intended to work with just the OF device ID, but real world legacy problems got in the way!

@IanAbbott thanks! I have no more questions, it's clear now.
